# Stylesheet not loaded because MIME type and file not found for node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am fiddling with twitter bootstrap using node.js and jade, however I am getting this stylesheet not loaded because MIME type and file not found even though the directory is path is correct, I am speculating that I need to "set up" the route on the server side first like python's bottle framework code below

for python's bottle framework

```
@route('/static/js/<filename>')
def js_static(filename):
     return static_file(filename, root='./static/js')

@route('/static/img/<filename>')
def img_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/img')

@route('/static/css/<filename>')  
def img_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/css')
```

is there a node.js equivalent? or alternatively, is my set up for jade correct?

Any hint would be much appreciated

jade file

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
head
    title title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/static/css/bootstrap.css', type='text/css')
  body
    p The open items are as follows:
    table.table.table-striped
      tr
        td "a"
        td "a1"
      tr
        td "b"
        td "b1"
    script(src='/static/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js')
    script(src='/static/js/bootstrap.js')
```

bootstrap.js is in directory

```
/static/js/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way with [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) and [Zappa](http://zappajs.org/)

File structure

```
├── app.coffee
└─┬ views
  └── index.jade
```

app.coffee

```
require('zappa') ->
  @get '/': -> @render 'index'
```

Comment: I need to use coffee script to use twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Well, coffee is just a tool. If you need something to look at, I have a project working on using Bootstrap, Jade, Backbone and so on. It's not complete but the framework is working. https://github.com/rixtox/metaphor